# RadGrid on changing grid mode after update

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

For some reason the code that I have below does not change the mode from edit mode to display mode once update is complete. Please advise.

```
protected void gridData_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridEditableItem editItem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
    GridEditManager editMan = editItem.EditManager;

    Label lblDataId = editItem.FindControl("lblDataId") as Label;
    TextBox txtDataName = editItem.FindControl("txtDataName ") as TextBox;

    string dataName = txtDataName.Text;

    int dataId = Convert.ToInt32(lblDataId .Text);
    stateBLL.UpdateState(dataId, dataName);

    gridData.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row will stay on "edit mode" unless you explicitly revert it back to "view mode". Try setting it to "view mode" when you finish updating, just before the `gridData.DataBind();` line add the following line of code...

```
e.Item.Edit = false;
```